# multiple background images not showing in IE and Safari

Tags: html, css

I have multiple background images on my 1 page- vertical scroll site that aren't showing up in Safari or IE.

IE doesn't work because I know that I am not running IE9.

Safari is 5.1.7

Are there any css hacks or ways to achieve my desired result of having the images show up cross browser?

What is it that developers do when they know that their design will have this problem in certain browsers?

**Edit**
I just installed Google Chrome, Version 26.0.1410.64 m
and the multiple images do not show up as well.

---

-Thanks for any replies (:

**EDIT**
http://jsbin.com/ucuyed/1/edit

link to HTML and jsbin

Comment: mutiple? how. packed in different pics, each in a div or just the one called background on the body or html tag? so nice to see your html markup in http://jsbin.com

Comment: hacks are never cross browser compatible, thats why they are hacks. so try to avoid using them, instead try to solve it by standards, maybe much easier with a little change in your html markup.

Comment: each is in a sepeart div. the first div is projects, about, contact. Each div has 1 background image. Works fine in Firefox

Comment: The first problem I see is that the links to the bg images don't work. Check those first. Otherwise, set all the background properties, like the position.

Comment: your pics are behind a https closed page, without webauth a browser can not load them for a no-user of your page :) thats why i changed it to http://placehold.it/ so you see its working nice, like expected http://jsbin.com/ucuyed/2/edit

Comment: so instead of using the path on my server, I should just use the path to my directory? When I did this I couldn't get them to show up for me.

Comment: and mulitple used ID in tags.. use them as class instead, well needs some change in your css too. not ready.. http://jsbin.com/ucuyed/3/edit nope you can use your own src.links but pics behind wall are just visible for logged in users.. maybe you want this.. so are there http direct links to them too?

Comment: maybe i should just drop the s from https and use http?

Comment: depends on your scripts.. but could work yes. also check your boxmodel html line:34 doubled id and so on, closing div a not opened one. that is the reason why mostly we use folded/tab spaced markup, to have controll whats "open" and should be "/closed" after.

Comment: I overlooked that, its sloppy markup atm, I tried just using http and this did not work. I haven't dealt with a server much before this.

Comment: Cant you just write the slash as a '/', in stead of using '%2f'. And why not point at the directory from the public_html root? like; '/img/aboutbackg.png'

Comment: @feskr, that's what I've been trying is using just 'img/aboutbackg.png' but this doesn't show the background when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved, perhaps I was too tired to be working on this last night.

While using `('img/contactbg.png')` and all the others did not work,

using ('http://mydomain.com/img/.... worked.

I was trying to use the server or was using the https:// as codelio pointed out.